# I need to convert the following condition into cassandra query

Tags: cassandra

```
SELECT * 
FROM NOTIFICATION.ADMIN_MESSAGE_TITLE 
WHERE ORGANIZATIONID = ?0 
  AND ((STARTTS >= ?1 AND STARTTS <= ?2) 
       OR (ENDTS >= ?1 AND ENDTS <= ?2))
```

These conditions should be converted into a Cassandra query. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you share the table definition?
If all the columns are in the primary key, with `ORGANIZATIONID` being the partition key, and `STARTTS` and `ENDTS` the first and second clustering columns, it should be a straightforward set of queries - CQL doesn't support the `OR` operator. If not, then you need ALLOW FILTERING, making the queries very expensive.

Comment: @MárioTavares makes a great point. We can't help you build a `WHERE` clause unless we know what the table's PRIMARY KEY definition looks like.

Comment: I want to correct something in previous comment. No matter what, you'll need 2 queries and manage the OR with application logic. And at least one of the queries will have to be ran with ALLOW FILTERING (therefore not ideal if `ORGANIZATIONID` is not the partition key), since both columns can't be simultaneously the first clustering column.